Lifetime movie about three middle-aged sisters and their relationship with their mother

Definitely a Lifetime movie, may not have been an "original" Lifetime movie but I know for sure that's the channel it was on. 
Live Action.
An American film and in English.
I watched it around 2010 or so but it had a '90s vibe to it. 
I think the setting was a suburban small American town.  

I distinctly remember how the movie started, three sisters (all grown woman, I think were all married with their own children) and their senior mother were driving in a car.  The mother was talking about how she was probably going to die soon because she is old and her daughters were all angry telling her she was just talking crazy because she is in good health. 
The movie revolved around the lives of the sisters and their mother.  
One of the daughters is married and has sons with a mean sort-of-man.  Not necessarily an abusive one, just not a pleasant one.  I remember in one scene he ordered his wife to make him a sandwich while she was busy with her family and her sisters became angry that she was taking orders like that.  Toward the end of the film, she confronts her husband and they take some sort of break I think.  After that, there is some sort of play or special event that I think one of their kids were in and they make up with each other or she forgives him.  That night she dies suddenly of a brain aneurysm while sitting at the kitchen table. 
At her daughter's funeral, the mother has a very hard time. In the weeks/months to come after her daughter's death, she is deep into mourning because she doesn't understand why her daughter died and not her. Her other daughters try to tell her she needs to appreciate the time she has left and try to get her start living a normal life again.  
Unfortunately, I do not remember much detail about the other two sisters.  
In the end the mother begins to appreciate life and is happy to still be able to enjoy time with her daughters and does not worry about dying anymore. 
